# observable boolean value not working in view?

Tags: angular

I have a component class that has in it:

```
  private ready = new Subject<boolean>;
  ready$ = this.ready.asObservable();

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ready.next(true)
    }, 1000);
  }
  ...
```

and then in the template I am doing:

```
<p *ngIf="ready$ | async">
  hi there
<p>
```

Yet I am never seeing my paragraph tag...

and if I do:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ready$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ready.next(true)
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I see the boolean print to the console.....  Why is this not working in my template?

Comment: Your code works in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isszc6?file=src/main.ts). Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example in StackBlitz?

Comment: @YongShun, I finally figured out how to reproduce my problem...  I forked your stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nae7tn?file=src/main.ts

Comment: But I check your demo I can see both messages are displayed in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

`ngAfterViewInit` triggered after the rendering is done, maybe it's not able insert your data into the DOM, because it's not there yet, but the setTimeout works, because it probably happens after the rendering.

Here is a fork for your example: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpdtpn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The *ngIf directive in your template is subscribing to the ready$ observable before it emits its first value. This means that the *ngIf condition evaluates to false initially and the `<p>` tag is not rendered.

Use a BehaviorSubject instead of a Subject. A BehaviorSubject takes an initial value in its constructor, so you can initialize it with a value of false and then emit a true value after 1 second in the ngOnInit method.

```
private ready = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
ready$ = this.ready.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.ready.next(true);
  }, 1000);
}
```